# SQL Funnel Analysis on Timestamps

Tags: sql

Goal: Analyze the % of users who add a product to cart, per filter applied to the product list page.

**Table 1: Applied Filter**

```
user_id | timestamp         | filter_name
123     | 2022-02-02 1:05pm | electronics
123     | 2022-02-02 1:08pm | household
123     | 2022-02-02 1:10pm | food
```

**Table 2: Added Product to Cart**

```
user_id | timestamp         | product_name
123     | 2022-02-02 1:06pm | *electronic_product*
123     | 2022-02-02 1:12pm | *food_product*
```

**Desired Results**

```
user_id | filter            | filter_count         | add_to_carts
123     | electronics       | 1                    | 1
123     | household         | 0                    | 0
123     | food              | 1                    | 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: as there is string manipulation necessary, can you tag the correct databse system

Comment: Sample data is fine, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh i put the desired result in the post

Comment: @jarlh im trying to join on user id = user id and also filter.timestamp < addmeal.timestamp  but that results in each filter record getting duplicate entries for every product the user added to cart

Comment: I see no specified result.

Comment: Use the same proper format as for the sample data! That part looks great.

Comment: Much better now!

Comment: How do you know a `*electronic_product*` is an electronic product?

Comment: @jarlh theres no actual way to link them at the moment :( so it would all be based on timestamps is what i'm looking for in the meantime. so you could re-frame add_to_carts as being based on add to carts that happened where that filter was the most recently applied filter before the add to cart event